# Missing Linked Server Provider on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I need to create Linked Server to MS Analysis Services, but my server does not have this provider installed. How to install it? Can't find any article about this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: when we talk about `providers` mainly we mean to say the `drivers`. so in your case I suspect the analysis service ole db provider/driver is missing and needs to be installed.

Comment: In my opinion you need [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295), Microsoft® OLEDB Provider for DB2 v5.0 for Microsoft SQL Server® 2014 `DB2OLEDB5_x86.msi and DB2OLEDB5_x64.msi` Instruction: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241541&clcid=0x409

Comment: @lad2025, yes, that's it. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem in SQL 2017. I installed [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2017 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55992) but I still do not see IBMDASQL in the provider list. My question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619171/ibmdasql-is-missing-from-linked-server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install **[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)**

> Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft SQL Server® 2014
>
> The Analysis Services OLE DB Provider is a COM component that software developers can use to create client-side applications that browse metadata and query data stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services. This provider implements both the OLE DB specification and the specification’s extensions for online analytical processing (OLAP) and data mining.
>
> Note: Microsoft Analysis Services OLE DB Provider requires Microsoft Core XML Services (MSXML) 6.0
>
> **Filename: X86 and x64 Package(SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi)**