# IBMDASQL is missing from Linked Server

Tags: db2, oledb, linked-server

I am trying to connect to our AS400 database from sql 2017 using linked servers but I do not see IBMDASQL in the provider.

[image]

However I can see IBMDASQL provider if I try to import data.
[image]

How can I add IBMDASQL to the provider list in linked servers?

Answer (score 0):

IBM client access software needed to be installed.